# How to pass a variable to "commandAction" in j2me?

Tags: java-me

I'm trying to make my very firs j2me program, so please bear with me...

My question: how can I pass a value of string variable to "commandAction"? I mean something like this:

```
public void test() {
    String myVariable = "hello";
    option1 = new Command("Option 1", Command.EXIT, 2);
    textBox.addCommand(option1);
    textBox.setCommandListener(this);
    Display.getDisplay(this).setCurrent(textBox);
}

public void commandAction(Command cmd, Displayable displayable) {
    if (cmd == option1) {
        print myVariable; // HOW TO MAKE THIS WORK?
}
```

How can I pass value of "myVariable" from "test" to "commandAction"? Does j2me have some "global variables" or how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an instance variable:

```
private String myVariable;

public void test() {
    myVariable = "hello";
    option1 = new Command("Option 1", Command.EXIT, 2);
    textBox.addCommand(option1);
    textBox.setCommandListener(this);
    Display.getDisplay(this).setCurrent(textBox);
}

public void commandAction(Command cmd, Displayable displayable) {
    if (cmd == option1) {
        print myVariable; 
    }
}
```